# Use Bootstrap on Vapor

Tags: swift, bootstrap-4, vapor

I am new to web development and couldn't find a clear answer.

Is it possible to use Bootstrap in Vapor with Swift 3?

Comment: I guess yes, because bootstrap its just a files of stylesheets (css), if in vapor you can use files with css extension, you should use it.

Comment: I guess you are right. I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap. You will either:

- Add the CDN links to your template files, i.e. `.leaf` files, which are in the `Resources/Views/` folder, or
- Download the Bootstrap files and add the CSS, JS, fonts, etc. to the `Public/` folder which can be accessed by all the pages.

For the first suggestion, you could add the CDN links to your `base.leaf`, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    #import("head")
</head>
    <body>
        #import("body")
    </body>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

For the second suggestion, you would place the files in here:

[image]

Then access the files like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/{CSS-FILE-NAME}">
    #import("head")
</head>
    <body>
        #import("body")
    </body>
    <script src="/{JS-FILE-NAME}"></script>
</html>
```